# Plotting columns in a list of data frames

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I have a list of data frames `Data_total_split` (125 data frames) and I want to plot, in each data frame, the column "Year" in X versus the column "Values" in Y. How can I do ? And how can I add a linear regression such as y=ax+b to obtain 2 new lists "a" and "b", the values from the regression in each data frame ?

```
> head(Data_total_split)
$`Soil_Grass.Paris.AC-228`
# A tibble: 5 x 6
   Year Sample_type Locality Chemicals Measuring_Unit  Values
  <dbl> <chr>       <chr>    <chr>    <chr>            <dbl>        
1  2016 Soil_Grass  Paris     AC-228   Mol/M2           277
2  2017 Soil_Grass  Paris     AC-228   Mol/M2           245
3  2018 Soil_Grass  Paris     AC-228   Mol/M2           195 
4  2019 Soil_Grass  Paris     AC-228   Mol/M2           190  
5  2020 Soil_Grass  Paris     AC-228   Mol/M2           160      

$`Fish.Paris.AC-228`
# A tibble: 5 x 6
   Year Sample_type Locality Chemicals Measuring_Unit  Values
  <dbl> <chr>       <chr>    <chr>    <chr>            <dbl>        
1  2016 Fish        Paris     AC-228   Mol/M2           125
2  2017 Fish        Paris     AC-228   Mol/M2           120
3  2018 Fish        Paris     AC-228   Mol/M2           117 
4  2019 Fish        Paris     AC-228   Mol/M2           107  
5  2020 Fish        Paris     AC-228   Mol/M2           100
```

Comment: Either (1) write a function to create the plot you want for each data frame, then `lapply` your function to the list, or (2) `bind_rows` your list into a single data frame and then use `Sample_type` to define facets.  You can draw your regression lines with `geom_smooth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Hope this can help (`DFList` is your list):

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
DFList <- list(structure(list(Year = 2016:2020, Sample_type = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Soil_Grass", class = "factor"), Locality = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Paris", class = "factor"), Chemicals = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "AC-228", class = "factor"), Measuring_Unit = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Mol/M2", class = "factor"), Values = c(277L, 
245L, 195L, 190L, 160L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(Year = 2016:2020, Sample_type = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Fish", class = "factor"), Locality = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Paris", class = "factor"), Chemicals = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "AC-228", class = "factor"), Measuring_Unit = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Mol/M2", class = "factor"), Values = c(125L, 
    120L, 117L, 107L, 100L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"))

#Function
myplot <- function(x)
{
  y <- ggplot(x,aes(Year, Values)) +
    geom_point(color='blue') + 
    geom_smooth(method='lm', formula= y~1+x)
  return(y)
}
#Plots
l1 <- lapply(DFList,myplot)
lapply(l1,plot)
```

Your plots will look like this:

[image]

Comment: First, thank you for your help, it works perfectly! And do you know whether it is possible to obtain a list with a the "a" and "b" values of the regression for each plot ?

Comment: @Sylvain You can obtain a dataframe with coefs using this: `dfcoefs <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(DFList,function(x) coef(lm(Values~Year,data = x)))))` Hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and quick answer.

Comment: A last question : how to add the title for each plot ? I tried `ggtitle(names(Data_total_split[x]))` but I got "invalid subscript type 'list' "

Comment: @Sylvain If you wanna add year as title then add to `myplot` `+ggtitle(unique(x$Year))` after `geom_smooth`

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Unfortunately, R did not add the title above each graph